# A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I loaded an image into a Picture Box using:

```
picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile()
```

and I save it by using:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
bm.Save(FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

It works perfectly fine when creating a new file, but when I try to replace the existing image, I get thrown the following runtime error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

So what can I do to solve this problem??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That because the image file is used by your `picturebox1.Image`, try to save it to different file path instead:

```
picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(FileName);
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image); 
bm.Save(@"New File Name", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

**Edit:** You could also add a copy from the image at the first place like:

```
picturebox1.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(FileName));
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image); 
bm.Save(FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);//no error will occurs here.
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to replace, can't I do that?

Comment: If you want to replace, you should remove the image first from the `pictureBox.Image` then replace, and then re-add it to the `pictureBox.Image`, you can also add a copy of your image in the picture box at the first place...

Comment: @Lakshani: don't forget to mark the answer that answers your question right as [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so others will know how your problem solved.

Comment: plus 1 for you bud

Answer (score 7):

The `FromFile` method locks the file, so use the **Image.FromStream()** method for reading the image:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Then save like you were before.

Comment: I think this may have fixed a problem I have been experiencing for months!

Comment: Of course! @ScruffyDuck, the method **Image.FromFile** will open that image file.

Comment: @Jon nut there isn't a saving method?

Comment: @Lakshani I'm sorry. I didn't get you. If you want to save picturebox's image then use - Bitmap bm = new Bitmat(pictureBox1.Image); bm.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Bmp);

Comment: I'm getting this same error while trying to save the file using .Save() method. Please refer to my code which is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25968726/84199

Comment: I also tried to read from memory stream instead of using .FromFile() method, but the error is still there while trying to save.

Comment: @MoizNgp Take look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file/8624114#8624114

Answer (score 4):

This can also happen if the path does not exist.

You could create the dir with:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName));
```

Answer (score 2):

When either a Bitmap object or an Image object is constructed from a file, the file remains locked for the lifetime of the object. As a result, you cannot change an image and save it back to the same file where it originated. http://support.microsoft.com/?id=814675

A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream:

```
Image.Save(..)  // throws a GDI+ exception because the memory stream is closed
```

http://alperguc.blogspot.in/2008/11/c-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi.html

**EDIT:** Just writing from memory. Saving to an 'intermediary' `MemoryStream` should work:

For example, replace this:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(thumbBMP);
thumbBMP.Dispose();
thumbBMP = null;
newBitmap.Save("~/image/thumbs/" + "t" + objPropBannerImage.ImageId, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

with something like:

```
string outputFileName = "...";
using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        thumbBMP.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(FileName);
Bitmap bm = new Bitmat(pictureBox1.Image); 
Image img = (Image)b;
img.Save(FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: you must define openfiledialog firstly. than read image from file and use these code. it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Jalal Aldeen Saa'd said, the picture box is using the file and locked from file replacement.

```
//unlock file by clearing it from picture box
if (picturebox1.Image != null)
{
   picturebox1.Image.Dispose();
   picturebox1.Image = null;
}

//put back the picture inside the pictureBox?
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```
public void SavePicture()
{
     Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.myBitmap)
     bm.Save("Output\\out.bmp" ,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you forget to add the filename:

```
bm.Save(@"C:\Temp\Download", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

And can be fixed by adding the file name:

```
bm.Save(@"C:\Temp\Download\Image.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Note: You don't actually have to add the extension for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void LoadPictureBoxWithImage( string ImagePath)
{
    Stream objInputImageStream = null;
    BitmapData bmdImageData = null;
    Bitmap bmpSrcImage = null, bmTemp = null;
    byte[] arrImageBytes = null;
    int bppModifier = 3;
    try
    {

        objInputImageStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (FileStream objFile = new FileStream(ImagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            objFile.CopyTo(objInputImageStream);
        }

        bmpSrcImage = new Bitmap(objInputImageStream);
        bppModifier = bmpSrcImage.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb ? 3 : 4;

        //reda from byte[] to bitmap               
        bmdImageData = bmpSrcImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpSrcImage.Width, bmpSrcImage.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmpSrcImage.PixelFormat);
        arrImageBytes = new byte[Math.Abs(bmdImageData.Stride) * bmpSrcImage.Height];

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmdImageData.Scan0, arrImageBytes, 0, arrImageBytes.Length);
        bmpSrcImage.UnlockBits(bmdImageData);

        pbSetup.Image = (Bitmap)bmpSrcImage.Clone();
        pbSetup.Refresh();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error in Function " + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "; " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (objInputImageStream != null)
        {
            objInputImageStream.Dispose();
            objInputImageStream = null;
        }
        if (bmdImageData != null)
        {
            bmdImageData = null;
        }
        if (bmpSrcImage != null)
        {
            bmpSrcImage.Dispose();
            bmpSrcImage = null;
        }
        if (bmTemp != null)
        {
            bmTemp.Dispose();
            bmTemp = null;
        }
        if (arrImageBytes != null)
        {
            arrImageBytes = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A generic error occurred in GDI+**

I also faced the same issue. I tried so many ways to fix this issue. Finally, I found a place where I have gone wrong. The problem is that I used space in the file path, which is not acceptable. Now it is working fine after removing the space in front of C after the apostrophe:

```
"SupplyItems":"C:\\inetpub\\HIBMS_Ver1\\BarcodeImages\\Supply\\"
```

instead... I used below one.

```
"SupplyItems":" C:\\inetpub\\HIBMS_Ver1\\BarcodeImages\\Supply\\"
```

Minor mistake but took a long time to find and to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that images created by Image.Clone() will still cause GDI+ errors as shown by the BAD code below, you must use the Image.FromStream() method for reading the image as shown in the solution on this page.

```
    //BAD CODE: the image we will try to save AFTER the original image has been cloned and disposed
    Image clonedImage;
    //load image from file, clone it then dispose
    using (var loadedFromDiskImage = Image.FromFile(filePath))
    {
         clonedImage = (Image) loadedFromDiskImage.Clone();
    }
```

```
//you might think the new image can be saved given the original is disposed
 //but this doesn't seem to be the way Clone() works
 //expect GDI+ error in line below:
 clonedImage.Save(filePath);
```