# Save and load MemoryStream to/from a file

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, memorystream

I am serializing an structure into a `MemoryStream` and I want to save and load the serialized structure.

So, How to Save a `MemoryStream` into a file and also load it back from file?

Comment: If you need to save to a file, why are you using a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: @Oded What should I use? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 446, accepted):

You may use `MemoryStream.WriteTo` or `Stream.CopyTo` (supported in framework version 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4) methods to write content of memory stream to another stream.

```
memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
```

Update:

```
fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

Comment: memoryStream.CopyTo didn't seem to work for me, while WriteTo did. I think perhaps it was because my memoryStream.Position wasn't 0

Comment: Yes that is correct. The difference between them is that CopyTo copies from whatever the current position is instead of always from the begining like WriteTo does.

Comment: Adding [`[file|memory]Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) before `CopyTo` will set the current position to 0, so that `CopyTo` will copy the complete stream.

Answer (score 329):

Assuming that MemoryStream name is `ms`.

This code writes down MemoryStream to a file:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)) {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
   ms.Read(bytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
   file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   ms.Close();
}
```

and this reads a file to a MemoryStream :

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
   file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
   ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
}
```

In .Net Framework 4+, You can simply copy FileStream to MemoryStream and reverse as simple as this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    file.CopyTo(ms);
```

And the Reverse (MemoryStream to FileStream):

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    ms.CopyTo(file);
```

Comment: Can I ask why you use FileMode.Create in the read sample vs FileMode.Open?

Comment: In the first code block, instead of manually copying memory stream to array, you can use built-in `ms.ToArray()` function.

Comment: It's important to set ms.Position = 0, otherwise byte array (and file) will contain all zeros.

Comment: @Fernando68 the construct `using (...){ }` has the exactly the same effect.

Comment: Just as a warning to others 'using (FileStream' and 'ms.CopyTo(file)'  sets the position tothe end of the file and you need to reset the memorystream afterwards.

Comment: @GregoryKhrapunovich , Its like a cassete tape, while we create it... we write to the very end. Now the tape has to be rewound before we put it in the walkman.

Answer (score 78):

The stream should really by disposed of even if there's an exception (quite likely on file I/O) - using clauses are my favourite approach for this, so for writing your MemoryStream, you can use:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
    memoryStream.WriteTo(file);
}
```

And for reading it back:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
    file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
}
```

**If the files are large, then it's worth noting that the reading operation will use twice as much memory as the total file size**. One solution to that is to create the MemoryStream from the byte array - the following code assumes you won't then write to that stream.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, writable: false);
```

My research (below) shows that the internal buffer is the same byte array as you pass it, so it should save memory.

```
byte[] testData = new byte[] { 104, 105, 121, 97 };
var ms = new MemoryStream(testData, 0, 4, false, true);
Assert.AreSame(testData, ms.GetBuffer());
```

Answer (score 72):

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("1.dat"));

File.WriteAllBytes("1.dat", memoryStream.ToArray());
```

---

`.GetBuffer` can be used in some cases to get the internal buffer instead of allocating second array :

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("1.dat");
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, true, true); 

File.WriteAllBytes("1.dat", memoryStream.GetBuffer());
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will re-allocate the whole buffer (MemoryStream.ToArray) `byte[] copy = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray<byte>(count);`

Answer (score 24):

The combined answer for writing to a file can be;

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();    
FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
ms.WriteTo(file);
file.Close();
ms.Close();
```

Answer (score 19):

For loading a file, I like this a lot better

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
{
    fs.CopyTo(ms);
}
```

Comment: If file is opened in Microsoft Word - is there a way for creating a memory stream from that file? I am receiving an error 'file is opened by another process'

Comment: @FrenkyB I also run into this a lot. If you have the file open in Word or some other app then you can't get do it. Just close the file in Word.

Comment: @FrenkyB Can you do a File.Copy? I have found that to work, then read from that file into a stream and delete the new file... horrible, but seems to work.

Answer (score 19):

**Save into a file**

```
Car car = new Car();
car.Name = "Some fancy car";
MemoryStream stream = Serializer.SerializeToStream(car);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, stream.ToArray());
```

**Load from a file**

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)))
{
    Car car = (Car)Serializer.DeserializeFromStream(stream);
}
```

where

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Serialization
{
    public class Serializer
    {
        public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
            return stream;
        }

        public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

> Originally the implementation of this class has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10390682/1375553)

and

```
[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use a Panel Control to add a image or even stream video, but you can save the image on SQL Server as **Image** or MySQL as **largeblob**. This code works for me a lot. Check it out.

Here you save the image

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.Bounds);
bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); // here you can change the Image format
byte[] Pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(Pic_arr, 0, Pic_arr.Length);
ms.Close();
```

And here you can load, but I used a PictureBox Control.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(picarr);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fotos.pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Hope helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ImageWriterUtil
{
    public class ImageWaterMarkBuilder
    {
        //private ImageWaterMarkBuilder()
        //{
        //}
        Stream imageStream;
        string watermarkText = "©8Bytes.Technology";
        Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Brush Script MT", 30, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Point position;
        public ImageWaterMarkBuilder AddStream(Stream imageStream)
        {
            this.imageStream = imageStream;
            return this;
        }
        public ImageWaterMarkBuilder AddWaterMark(string watermarkText)
        {
            this.watermarkText = watermarkText;
            return this;
        }
        public ImageWaterMarkBuilder AddFont(Font font)
        {
            this.font = font;
            return this;
        }

        public ImageWaterMarkBuilder AddFontColour(Color color)
        {
            this.brush = new SolidBrush(color);
            return this;
        }
        public ImageWaterMarkBuilder AddPosition(Point position)
        {
            this.position = position;
            return this;
        }

        public void CompileAndSave(string filePath)
        {

            //Read the File into a Bitmap.
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.imageStream, false))
            {
                using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {


                    //Determine the size of the Watermark text.
                    SizeF textSize = new SizeF();
                    textSize = grp.MeasureString(watermarkText, font);

                    //Position the text and draw it on the image.
                    if (position == null)
                        position = new Point((bmp.Width - ((int)textSize.Width + 10)), (bmp.Height - ((int)textSize.Height + 10)));
                    grp.DrawString(watermarkText, font, brush, position);

                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        //Save the Watermarked image to the MemoryStream.
                        bmp.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                       // string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
                        // outPuthFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), fileName + "_outputh.png");
                        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                            memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
                            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                            memoryStream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Usage :-

```
ImageWaterMarkBuilder.AddStream(stream).AddWaterMark("").CompileAndSave(filePath);
```