# Serializing/deserializing with memory stream

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, memorystream

I'm having an issue with serializing using memory stream. Here is my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// serializes the given object into memory stream
/// </summary>
/// <param name="objectType">the object to be serialized</param>
/// <returns>The serialized object as memory stream</returns>
public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object objectType)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, objectType);
    return stream;
}

/// <summary>
/// deserializes as an object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stream">the stream to deserialize</param>
/// <returns>the deserialized object</returns>
public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    object objectType = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    return objectType;
}
```

The error I'm getting is as follow:
stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: blah....

I'm not exactly sure what is causing the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example of the call:

```
Dog myDog = new Dog();
myDog.Name= "Foo";
myDog.Color = DogColor.Brown;

MemoryStream stream = SerializeToStream(myDog)

Dog newDog = (Dog)DeserializeFromStream(stream);
```

Comment: Provide the code you're using to call your methods.

Comment: can you show us how you using this code ? It's suspicious that this parameter is named objectType

Comment: I don't have any problem by executing your example of codes. Do you have other portion that dealing with the stream object ?

Comment: Same here, code works. Can you show your Dog class ? What is that DogColor type ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
public void Run()
{
    Dog myDog = new Dog();
    myDog.Name= "Foo";
    myDog.Color = DogColor.Brown;

    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", myDog.ToString());

    MemoryStream stream = SerializeToStream(myDog);

    Dog newDog = (Dog)DeserializeFromStream(stream);

    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", newDog.ToString());
}
```

Where the types are like this:

```
[Serializable]
public enum DogColor
{
    Brown,
    Black,
    Mottled
}

[Serializable]
public class Dog
{
    public String Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public DogColor Color
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Dog: {0}/{1}", Name, Color);
    }
}
```

and the utility methods are:

```
public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
    return stream;
}

public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    return o;
}
```

Comment: I implement the code that you suggested now and code throw this exception:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

It occurs in the line 

 object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: okay I made a terrible mistake in the Deserialization constructor. One of my properties' info was wrong (i.e. ... = info.GetValue("HereWasWrong_ItWasNonExistingThing", typeof(int));)  

here it is a good link for this job, and someone may need it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C
 also thanks to Cheeso, the answer is good.

Comment: BinaryFormatter serialization is obsolete and should not be used. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.

Answer (score 7):

Use Method to Serialize and Deserialize Collection object from memory. This works on Collection Data Types. This Method will Serialize collection of any type to a byte stream. Create a Seperate Class `SerilizeDeserialize` and add following two methods:

```
public class SerilizeDeserialize
{

    // Serialize collection of any type to a byte stream

    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter binSerializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            binSerializer.Serialize(memStream, obj);
            return memStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    // DSerialize collection of any type to a byte stream

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] serializedObj)
    {
        T obj = default(T);
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(serializedObj))
        {
            BinaryFormatter binSerializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            obj = (T)binSerializer.Deserialize(memStream);
        }
        return obj;
    }

}
```

How To use these method in your Class:

```
ArrayList arrayListMem = new ArrayList() { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven" };
Console.WriteLine("Serializing to Memory : arrayListMem");
byte[] stream = SerilizeDeserialize.Serialize(arrayListMem);

ArrayList arrayListMemDes = new ArrayList();

arrayListMemDes = SerilizeDeserialize.Deserialize<ArrayList>(stream);

Console.WriteLine("DSerializing From Memory : arrayListMemDes");
foreach (var item in arrayListMemDes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: You can use this code to serialize the object(s) to and from a byte stream for storage in isolated storage or remote storage.  With the help of this you can Persist a Collection Between Application Sessions.

Comment: Thank you for this.
Why everyone says that you cannot serialize an anonymous type though?

Answer (score 5):

It can be done easily by using [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0) in .Net 6
using System.Text.Json;

```
Examlple ex = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Example>(ms);
Console.WriteLine(ex.Value);

class Example
{
    string Value {get; set; }
}
```

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-6.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_System_IO_Stream_System_Object_System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) for serialization.

Comment: This is only valid from .Net6 onwards

Comment: @g0np thank you for pointing it out. I have mentioned the .Net 6 version in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`BinaryFormatter` may produce invalid output in some specific cases. For example it will omit unpaired surrogate characters. It may also have problems with values of interface types. Read this [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) including community content.

If you find your error to be persistent you may want to consider using XML serializer like `DataContractSerializer` or `XmlSerializer`.