# How to send Information between computers on the same local network via IP adress (WCF or Sockets)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets

I have coded an addressbook program, which manages a list of contacts and so on. 
Now I want to be able to send one contact to another computer on the same local network. I am pretty new to C# (I started some months ago) and I have already read a lot about WCF, but it seems like I always would need some kind of server (like IIS) to host a service, where my client program would listen at. But what if I don't have anything like a server to host that service?

**All I want to do is enter the IP of the computer who should receive the contact and then it will get the contact**.

How can i achieve that on an "easy" way? I dont know much about TCP/Ip stuff yet.

The contact should be sent as string in XML format or as object (or whatever is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that create a WCF service for your needs is not worth it, you only need to pass simple objects and WCF is much more powerful and much harder to use.

What I suggest that you use sockets for you needs, you can use the framework [Socket Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx), but [TcpListener Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TcpClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) are much more easy to use.

If you need to pass your own types between the services you can use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012549/send-typed-objects-through-tcp-or-sockets) or you can just map them to an xmls.

Comment: OKay thanks I have found an easy example for TcpListener and TcpClient:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182751/server-client-send-receive-simple-text (that is basicly the same as on msdn)

And it works great for me, so I think i will use that for my use.