# Json.Net JToken does not serialize all properties on Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: c#, android, serialization, xamarin.forms, json.net

I have a cross-platform Xamarin.Forms app that uses Json.Net to serialize and deserialize a class `JMessage`, which was taken from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012549/send-typed-objects-through-tcp-or-sockets) on the site. The class looks like this:

```
    public class JMessage
    {
        public Type Type { get; set; }
        public JToken Value { get; set; }

        public static JMessage FromValue<T>(T value)
        {
            return new JMessage { Type = typeof(T), Value = JToken.FromObject(value) };
        }

        public static string Serialize(JMessage message)
        {
            return JToken.FromObject(message).ToString();
        }

        public static JMessage Deserialize(string data)
        {
            return JToken.Parse(data).ToObject<JMessage>();
        }
    }
```

Everything is fine and dandy in the UWP and iOS versions of the app and nothing breaks. However, the Android version only serializes the `Value` property and completely ignores the `Type` property, causing things to break when the `JMessage` is deserialized. For example:

```
{
    "Value":{
       serialized properties go here...
    }
}
```

This seems to be a bug that spans across all Android devices, as I've tested it on 3 different Android devices, plus an emulator. The `JMessage` used to serialize and deserialize just fine so I'm not entirely sure what's happening now. Any answers?

Comment: What build of Json.NET are you using?  I don't think Newtonsoft provides a xamarin build.

Comment: @dbc I'm using 10.0.3, which I'm pretty sure is the latest stable. I also thought that they do provide Xamarin support? At least that's what they say on their [website.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear enough.  Is it one of the official Newtonsoft builds from https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/ or from elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, it's from NuGet.