# Save structure in binary file and then read from it

Tags: c#

My program(in WinForms) is some kind of testing of some subject. I have such structure, where I save my questions of this test:

```
Dictionary<int, Question> questions = new Dictionary<int, Question>();

public class Question
{
    public Question(string q_text,  Dictionary<string, bool> ans)
    {
        text = q_text;
        answers = ans;
    }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> answers { get; set; }       
}
```

I want to keep my questions(exactly `Dictionary<int, Question> questions = new Dictionary<int, Question>();`)  in binary file and every time I start the program, it will read from this. I've never worked with binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize the object and save it in a file. But you have to mark your class with [Serializable]

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

/// <summary>
/// Persists the object on HD
/// </summary>
public static void PersistObject()
{
    Logger.Debug("PersistObject: Started");
    // Persist to file
    FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(_filePath);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSave);
    stream.Close();
    
    Logger.Debug("PersistObject: Ended");
}

/// <summary>
/// Loads the object.
/// </summary>
public static void LoadObject()
{
    try
    {
        Logger.Debug("LoadObject: Started");
        // Open file to read saved DailyUsers object
        if (File.Exists(_filePath))
        {
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(_filePath);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    
            object deserializedObject = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
        Logger.Debug("LoadObject: Ended");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: what library should I add for Logger?

Comment: Regret. I should use another method, because I need not to install new software for this task.

Comment: just ignore the Logger part. Its not necessary

Comment: I should serialize every object of Question or can I just write into file Dictionary<int, Question> questions = new Dictionary<int, Question>()? And how to use LoadObject method? It doesn't return anything.

Comment: No just serialize the whole dictionary

Comment: In the persist object method replace object to save variable with your questions dictionary.

Comment: What's the problem there? You can handle it the way you want. Check if the object is null or save null.

Comment: I managed to successfully write dictionary in bin file. Please, help me to Load it from file. I just don't understand your method, Can you explain it or rewrite for Dictionary? How to get Dictionary from file?

Comment: If you need further help feel free to comment here again

Comment: `using System;` and `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do that using **serialization** so check the following code:

```
   Dictionary<int, Question> questions = new Dictionary<int, Question>();

    [Serializable]
    public class Question
    {
        public Question(string q_text, Dictionary<string, bool> ans)
        {
            text = q_text;
            answers = ans;
        }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, bool> answers { get; set; }

        public static void Save(Question q,Stream st)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf =
                new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            bf.Serialize(st, q);

        }

        public static void SaveMany(Dictionary<int, Question> questions,Stream st)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf =
                new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            bf.Serialize(st, questions);

        }
        public static Question Load(Stream st)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf =
                new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            Question q = (Question)bf.Deserialize(st);

            return q;
        }
        public static Dictionary<int, Question> LoadMany(Stream st)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf =
                new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            Dictionary<int, Question> q = (Dictionary<int, Question>)bf.Deserialize(st);

            return q;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also write an example, where you call these two functions. Cause, I am a bit confused. For example, I want to call Load function in Constructor. And method Save in the FinishButton_Click method.

Comment: And I can't call method Save. Please, show full example

Comment: Can I save just save Dictionary<int, Question> questions = new Dictionary<int, Question>() instead of every object?

Answer (score -1):

You are wanting to serialize your objects using the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390356/c-sharp-serializing-deserializing-with-memory-stream) will give you the code you need to accomplish this.  But be aware that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is NOT serializable, so you will not be serialize it directly.  Instead, consider using `List<KeyValuePair<int, Question>>` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) *is* serializable.

Comment: Well, I stand SOMEWHAT corrected.  You can serialize a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in binary format, but not to XML.  I personally have run up against this in the past, which prompted my warning.  Here is more detail on it, though:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member