# c# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document to Stream

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I have a active document :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
```

How I can convert this to stream?

Or even better, how to send active document to rest web service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which rest-service? If it's SharePoint or the like i'm used to just calling the SaveAs function as follows:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
document.SaveAs("https://www.contoso.sharepoint.com/Documents/Document1.docx");
```

Edit: P.S. You can serialize anything to Stream.
found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390356/c-sharp-serializing-deserializing-with-memory-stream)

```
public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
    return stream;
}

public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    return o;
}
```

Comment: No, it is a 3rd party Restfull service

Comment: Doesn't work - a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document` is not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Save to a temp file then read file content as required by the rest service, e.g. byte array. Or use Open XML SDK if older Word formats are not required.