# How to Save a Binary Representation to file

Tags: c#, sql, pdf, binary

I have the following textual binary representation: "0x255044462D312E340D0A25FFFFFFF..."
I know it's a pdf.
I know it's the textual represantation from a sql server column (image data type).

But im lost to find out how to save this binary to a pdf file on my disk and view the content.

Maybe someone can hint me in the right direction.

Best Regards and Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is not binary, it is hexadecimal.

Comment: i tried to treat it as a hex string and therefore convert it to a byte array, but the length is uneven.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that it is a PDF file (at least it masquerades like on. You have hexadecimally encoded bytes; the first read:

```
255044462D312E340D0A

%PDF-1.4<CR><LF>
```

So you appear to have a PDF 1.4 string.

Just take two characters from the string, treat them as hex, convert them to the correct byte and write them to a file. Write binary, not textually (you don't want to add additional line-breaks in there, PDF is too binary to let that work.

(I did the conversion using this site: http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database you are working with or how you are getting your string that you have above.

Many databases allow you to save binary data as a `blob` or some other byte array type. I believe in MSSQL this is called an "image" but I am not 100% on that. I would start by looking into the two following links in order. The first link talks about how to pull byte array data from a database. The example is in Visual Basic but should be easily changed to C# if that is what you are using.

The second link contains an example of how to save that byte array data to the file system.

I would also suggest posting some of the code you have tried as well so that the community may comment and point out areas you possibly had misunderstandings on.

1.) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308042
2.) [Save and load MemoryStream to/from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Its a Microsoft SQL Database. The point is, i do not have access directly to the database. i just got this "String". and i want to save this binary data to my disk as a pdf.

Comment: How did you get the string? You may also want to look at this StackOverflow question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: i got it through a select statement in the output window of the microsoft sql management studio.

Comment: So if you can connect to the DB through the MS SSMS window, why can you not connect to the database programmatically and pull the blob / image that way?

Comment: This is party of my evaluation... so is it not possible just with this hexadecimal binary(?) string to rebuild the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/ can read in binary data and you can call .Save() and it will make the PDF file to disk for you.