# How do I save byte arrays i.e. byte[] to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I know how to save Streams, but I want to take that stream and create thumbnails and other sized images, but I don't know how to save a byte[] to the Azure Blob Storage.

This is what I'm doing now to save the Stream:

```
 // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
        CloudBlockBlob _blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("SampleImage.jpg");

        // upload from Stream object during file upload
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);

        // But what about pushing a byte[] array?  I want to thumbnail and do some image manipulation
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This used to be in the Storage Client library (version 1.7 for sure) - but they removed it in version 2.0

> "All upload and download methods are now stream based, the FromFile,
>   ByteArray, Text overloads have been removed."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx

Creating a read-only memory stream around the byte array is pretty lightweight though:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(data, writable: false)) {
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
}
```

#### Update: UploadFromByteArray is back

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfrombytearray.aspx) - from what I can tell in [the source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/9f583bc35b8535bae01f1b3b10beb7edc3054756/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Blob/CloudBlockBlob.cs), this came back for version 3.0 and is still there for version 4.0.

Comment: Ahhh, so a definitive no, its no longer available.  Gotcha.  Thanks.

Comment: Can we achieve the same in PowerShell? Especially in the context of inline [deployment script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template#use-inline-scripts) running in ARM template?

Comment: Prefere async :  myBlobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true); //with overwrite

Answer (score 17):

Using the new SDK `azure.storage.blob`

```
var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(storageConnectionString, containerName);
BlobClient blob = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

using(var ms = new MemoryStream(data, false))
{
     await blob.UploadAsync(ms);
}
```

Comment: thanks for new methods, have a small query on blobName .. is it file name that we can use here as blobname

Comment: Yes, blobname is filename!

Comment: @EnigmaState you can use the whole path with directories, and when you use Azure Storage Explorer it transforms in directories for a better visualisation.
Example:
folder1/folder2/filename.txt

Comment: What kind of type is 'data'?

Comment: 'data' is byte arrays i.e. byte[]

Answer (score 8):

update:

UploadFromByteArray is back.

```
public void UploadFromByteArray (
    byte[] buffer,
    int index,
    int count,
    [OptionalAttribute] AccessCondition accessCondition,
    [OptionalAttribute] BlobRequestOptions options,
    [OptionalAttribute] OperationContext operationContext
)
```

<del>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfrombytearray.aspx</del>

new link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfrombytearray?view=azure-dotnet-legacy

Comment: Link gives a 404

Answer (score 5):

I also know nothing about Azure, but using Streams, you could approach it as follows:

```
//byte[] data;

using(var ms = new MemoryStream(data, false))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: so you can only upload streams, so you have to convert each time?  There is no way to just push a byte array?

Comment: I don't know anything about Azure. Sorry.

Comment: @Shane, I think if you use the MemoryStream constructor as per my edit above, there will be no copying of the byte array, so I'd view this approach as efficient.

Comment: My testing (detailed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file/14748265#14748265 ) suggests pretty strongly that it does re-use that byte array.

Answer (score -1):

This is the function I currently use:

```
//CREATE FILE FROM BYTE ARRAY
public static string createFileFromBytes(string containerName, string filePath, byte[] byteArray)
{

    try {

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("StorageConnectionString").ConnectionString);



        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

        if (container.Exists == true) {
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);


            try {
                using (memoryStream == new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)) {
                    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
                }
                return "";
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        } else {
            return "Container does not exist";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```