# Is there any way of writing file to Azure Blob Storage directly from C# application?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create a new C# console application that writes into the blob storage directly from the code. I am able to create a local file and upload it to the blob. But the requirement is writing the content directly to blob instead of creating a file and uploading to Blob.I am not being able to achieve this. I searched for the related web resources but couldn't find anything that would help in this issue.
I am looking for suggestions/help.

Comment: What kind of data you’re trying to save? Is it text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save byte arrays i.e. byte\[\] to Azure Blob Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115212/how-do-i-save-byte-arrays-i-e-byte-to-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, its csv content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty straight forward. See the code below:

```
    static void SaveTextAsBlob()
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("storage-account-connection-string");
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container-name");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob-name.csv");
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "text/csv";
        string blobContents = GetCsvTextSomehow();
        blob.UploadText(blobContents);
    }
```