# Upload string to Azure Blob

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have had a look at this following link to upload a string to azure blob. my task requirement does not allow me to store the string as a file.

[Is there any way of writing file to Azure Blob Storage directly from C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220364/is-there-any-way-of-writing-file-to-azure-blob-storage-directly-from-c-sharp-app)

It is using CloudStorageAccount in WindowsAzure.Storage  which is deprecated already as per [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage)

I am trying to use Azure.Storage.Blobs library. HOwever, there's no longer UploadString method as per [this microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.upload?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClient_Upload_System_String_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobUploadOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

any advices? thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can upload a stream, so you can get the content of your string as a byte array, create a memory stream and upload it.

```
BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, "myContainer");
container.Create();

BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient("myString");

var myStr = "Hello!"
var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myStr);
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(content))
    blob.Upload(ms);
```

Comment: How to upload the same string separated by new lines (say I want to split the words into new lines) when I download and view the blob?

Comment: @Deepak Add the newlines to the string before `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`.

Comment: Thanks, @Gusman. I was able to do it with the help of `Environment.NewLine` before the one you said.