# How to load a PDF into memory then read it via acrobat reader?

Tags: c#, pdf, memory

What I am trying to do is load a pdf into memory from a flash drive, then read the pdf via acrobat reader. The idea is that if the user removes the flash he/she can still read the pdf since it was loaded into the memory/RAM. 
I tried to use the codes below which I got from this thread 
[Save and load MemoryStream to/from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file)

This is used to write the file

```
FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Read(bytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
file.Close();
ms.Close();
```

This is used to read the file

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
file.Close();
ms.Close();
```

I am relatively new to programming and I am trying to learn c#. It may seem like a silly question but I can not understand how implement the code. 
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the file to a location, then load up the file into Adobe from the fileLocation. I am not certain you can pass a memory stream to Adobe Reader directly.

Get the path of the PDF file and do this:

```
//Get the path
var path = @"C:\Users\MyUser\My Documents\MyPdf.pdf"
//Open adobe reader with the file
Process.Start(path);
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! You just saved weeks of research/googling :D