# C# Write stream that can't be contained in memory to file

Tags: c#, .net, stream

### Background:

I'm using an API that for a certain call returns a `System.IO.Stream`. The content is humongous and cannot be contained in RAM, and needs to be persisted. The size ranges from a couple of hundred MiB to a few GiB. The api is not something I can access other than the call I am making, but it has to be used. I cannot increase the amount of memory available to the program or switch to 64 bit.

### What I've tried:

Simply doing

```
var output = api.getStream();
System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\myfile.extension");
streamWriter.Write(output);
```

fails not because I'm writing an arbitrary binary as a string, but rather due to that when the first line is run (where output is assigned) the program crashes with a `System.InsufficientMemoryException`.

When trying the approaches outlined in the most upvoted answers to this post: [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c) I also get an out of memory error once the line where I get the stream from the api is called.

I've also tried approaches such as `api.getStream.CopyTo(myFileStream)` as suggested in an answer to this post: [Save and load MemoryStream to/from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file) , but still get a system out of memory exception.

### The resulting question:

Does anyone know how to write an arbitrarily large IO stream to file in C# when the stream is supplied from an api-call to an external library?

Comment: If API you're calling (`getStream()`) fails because it exhausts all available memory then there isn't much you can do in your own code. I don't know its prototype but I guess it's returning a `byte[]`, in this case it **must** be changed to - let's say - `IEnumerable<byte>` or `IEnumerable<byte[]>` - or provide a callback function to process data chunks, no workarounds. Oh, well, yes you _may_ call it in another process and access shared memory to read it chunk by chunk but this will just move your issue little bit forward, it won't solve it.

Comment: It sounds like this is more of a bug in the underlying getStream API but you've haven't told us what that is so any answers are going to be speculative at best.