# how to open file after read image bytes from the database

Tags: c#, winforms

i have used below code for showing image in image picture box, now i would like add code for opening file (pdf,image,...) after reading from database

```
            int imageID = Convert.ToInt32(imageIDComboBox.Text);

            // read image bytes from the database and display in picture box
            Byte[] imageByteArray = ProductDB.ReadImage(imageID);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray);

            imagePictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            ms.Close();
```

i have tried to used below code but it does not recognize Response.

```
   ms.writeto(Response.outputstream)
```

Comment: probabbly a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Save the File somewhere. I suggest you use the GetTempPath method to obtain a temp file name.

after you have saved the file you can open it with the default program of the machine by using the Process class

some pseudo code:

```
string fileName = "C:\temp\foo.pdf"; //or use Path.GetTempPath()
ms.Write(new StreamWriter(filename)); //you may want to use a using statement for your file stream to ensure the file is closed
Process.Start(filename);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx
https://www.dotnetperls.com/process

**EDIT**

It seems my pseudo code does not work correctly ;-) here's another snippet:

```
    Byte[] imageByteArray = ProductDB.ReadImage(imageID);
    string fileName = Path.GetTempPath();

    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, imageByteArray);

    Process.Start(fileName);
```

Comment: thanks, i got error "No overload for method 'Write' takes 1 arguments", please help what is the problem, also  variable "filename"and "fileName" are not same.