# Unable to close and delete open file (.docx) that I checked if was corrupted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, docx

The problem I'm encountering is regarding the validation of a .docx document, to validate I'm using the next method:

```
 public static bool ValidateWordDocument(string filepath)
    {
        WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument;
        try
        {
            wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true);
            wordprocessingDocument.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"El archivo {filepath} esta corrupto o se trata de un archivo ");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But when it launches the exception (because the file is corrupted and cannot open it) leaves the file open and cannot be closed in the catch because it's out of context the WordprocessingDocument "instance?".

Then, when I have to delete the file I had to validate I can't because it's open by another process:
[Error Deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZBq2.png)

Thank you.

Comment: What library does `WordprocessingDocument` come from?

Comment: WordprocessingDocument Class
Definition
Namespace:
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Assembly:
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll

Comment: The exception occurs on the .Open (since it's (sometimes) a corrupted file and cannot open it)

Comment: I would suggest loading the file into a `MemoryStream`, and passing that into `WordprocessingDocument`. This will ensure no file locks are held.

Comment: while researching I though about that, but I wasn't sure how to do it since I have just started learning .net, but thanks, I'll try it and learn abuot MemoryStream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save and load MemoryStream to/from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe changing it to something like this helps:

```
  try
    {
        wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"El archivo {filepath} esta corrupto o se trata de un archivo ");
        return false;
    }
finally{
 wordprocessingDocument.Close();
}
```