# How to find reason for Generic GDI+ error when saving an image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+, system.drawing

Having a code that works for ages when loading and storing images, I discovered that I have *one single image* that breaks this code:

```
const string i1Path = @"c:\my\i1.jpg";
const string i2Path = @"c:\my\i2.jpg";

var i = Image.FromFile(i1Path);
i.Save(i2Path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

The exception is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException occurred
>
> **A generic error occurred in GDI+.**
>
> at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
> at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
> at ...

As far as I can see, there is nothing special about the image. It is approx 250 pixels in size and can be opened in e.g. Windows Image Viewer or Paint.NET:

[image]

*(Since the image above, after being uploaded to Stack Overflow does not produce the error anymore, I've put [the original image here](https://www.magerquark.de/misc/i1.jpg))*

What I discovered is that upon calling the [`Save` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_), the destination image file is being created with zero bytes.

I am really clueless on what causes the error.

**My questions:**

- Can you think of any special thing that would hinder .NET from saving the image?
- Is there any way (beside panicing) to narrow down these kind of errors?

Comment: MSDN says a Bitmap loaded from a Stream requires the Stream to remain in existence as long as the Bitmap exists.

Comment: Unreleated to your problem: But the same exception occoures if the path does not exist (took me a while to figure out I had a typo). Might help someone else.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

While I still did not find out the reason what exactly caused the error when saving the image, I found a workaround to apply:

```
const string i1Path = @"c:\my\i1.jpg";
const string i2Path = @"c:\my\i2.jpg";

var i = Image.FromFile(i1Path);

var i2 = new Bitmap(i);
i2.Save(i2Path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I.e. by copying the image internally into a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) instance and saving this image instead of the original image, the error disappeared.

I'm assuming that by copying it, the erroneous parts the caused the original `Save` call to fail are being removed an/or normalized, thus enabling the save operation to succeed.

[image: saved image i2.jpg]

Interestingly, the so stored image has a smaller file on disk (16 kB) than its original source (26 kB).

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had to force garbage collection afterwards, on account of the 'out of memory exception' that was caused.

Comment: Worked for me too - no idea why. Only had the issue with jpg images (png etc were fine)

Comment: I had this issue with .bmp, .jpg, and .png but I wasn't loading a file, I was creating it in memory and trying to save it. `CAUSE:` the original bitmap is tied to the stream it loaded from (`FileStream` or `MemoryStream`).  The cloned bitmap it not tied to a stream, as it copied the pixel bytes.  It _might_ also have worked to `Freeze` the original bitmap before saving it.

Comment: I got this error for the second  time, some how the first time I used the same solution as u. but the second time it's not working

Comment: i have an issue of the picture quality dropping rapidly, how do i fix this

Answer (score 21):

First of all make sure, that the desired folder has Read/Write permissions. Changing the permissions solved this problem for me.

Comment: That's like 90% of the cases :-)

Comment: Its almost always a 'cant write' error. So also make sure the filename doesn't contain slashes or something.

Answer (score 9):

Solution is here, you must dispose image object to release the memory on the server.
Try use `using` statement. Make sure destination directory on server exists too.

Comment: This sounds like a _really_ bad answer to me.

Comment: "Make sure destination directory on server exists" was my issue

Comment: @UweKeim - a `using` on a temporary `IDisposable` object just ensures the GC is called for it as soon as it is safe to do so.

Comment: "Make sure destination directory on server exists" was my issue as well

Comment: "Make sure destination directory on server exists" was my issue as well. So easy to overlook.

Answer (score 6):

The reason may be that the image is loaded lazily and the loading process is not yet finished when you try to save it.

Following what's said in [this blog post](http://csharp-tricks.blogspot.ch/2010/10/allgemeiner-fehler-in-gdi.html) (assuming you're German by the picture you linked in your question) provides a possible solution. Also [this SO question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105561/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi) accepted answer indicates this is due to the fact the image file you're trying to save to is locked.

**EDIT**
For Ulysses Alves, from the linked blog entry: If you load an image using `Image.FromFile()` it remains locked until it is disposed of. This prevents calls to `Save()`.

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\test\\test1.jpg");
pictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\\test\\test2.jpg");
```

The above code throws an error.

To make it work, you need to copy the image. The following code works:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\test\\test1.jpg");
Image copy = pictureBox1.Image;
copy.Save("C:\\test\\test2.jpg")
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything related with this subject in the linked post. Could you please provide us a code example in your answer?

Comment: My guess is that the line Image copy = pictureBox1.Image; is not creating a copy, but merely creating a new reference.

Answer (score 4):

I found this question because I also faced the similar error and the file was **actually created with zero length** (if you don't see any file, first check the permissions to write into folder as other answers suggest). Although my code was slightly different (I use `stream` to read the image from memory, not from file), I think my answer may be helpful to anyone facing similar problem.

It may looks counter-intuitive, but you can't really dispose memory stream until you finish with image.

**NOT WORKING**:

```
Image patternImage;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(patternBytes)) {
    patternImage = new Bitmap(ms);
}

patternImage.Save(patternFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Just don't dispose the stream until you done with image.

**WORKS**:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(patternBytes)) {
    patternImage = new Bitmap(ms);
    patternImage.Save(patternFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

What is misleading:

- Error message doesn't really tell you anything
- You can see the image properties, like width and height, but can't
  save it

Comment: I had a similar kind of issue and this solution worked for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: is it mentioned in the documentation about reading an image and converting it into a bitmap before it is saved?

Answer (score 3):

my solution was to make, write temp content (File.WriteAllText) just before saving the file

**Here is the code:**

```
var i = Image.FromFile(i1Path);
File.WriteAllText(i2Path, "empty");  // <---- magic goes here
i.Save(i2Path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Please try and let me know

Comment: I can see where that would change when/where you got the exception if you did not have permission to create that file. :) :)  But it would be weird if this resolves the other issues in the OP.  `bitmap.Freeze(); bitmap.Save(...);` or `var other = new Bitmap(bitmap); other.Save(...);`  Both of these ensure that the bitmap being saved is not bound to a stream before `Save` is called.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have accidentally deleted the directory where image was getting stored.

Answer (score 1):

Key Information:

```
// Using System.Drawing.Imaging:
new Bitmap(image).Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

You **MUST** Cast the Image to a Bitmap to Save it.

Using:

```
// Using System.Drawing.Imaging:
image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

WILL throw the Error:

> Generic GDI+ error when saving an image

Answer (score 1):

Just use the visual studio as administrator  or run the application created by the code as administrator it should work smoothly.
It is user access rights issue.
I faced the same and resolved it by running visual studio as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I set `validateImageData` to `false`:

```cs
Image.FromStream(stream, validateImageData: false);
```

solution:

```cs
Image.FromStream(stream, validateImageData: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open in the program

```
const string i1Path = @"c:\my\i1.jpg";

const string i2Path = @"c:\my\i2.jpg";

var i = Image.FromFile(i1Path);

i.Save(i2Path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

i.Dispose();
```