# Convert BitmapSource to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, wpf, memorystream, bitmapsource

How Do I convert BitmapSource to MemoryStream. Though I tried some code:

```
private Stream StreamFromBitmapSource(BitmapSource writeBmp)
{
    Stream bmp;
    using (bmp = new MemoryStream())
    {                    
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(writeBmp));
        enc.Save(bmp);                                     
    }

   return bmp;
}
```

It doesn't give any error but after putting debugging point it is showing some exceptions which are listed below.

> Capacity: 'printStream.Capacity' threw an exception of type
>   'System.ObjectDisposedException'  Length: 'printStream.Length' threw
>   an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'  Position:
>   'printStream.Position' threw an exception of type
>   'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Comment: Thanks! Clemens, I gave my votes to the answers posted. :), and I want my color frames to get save on memory buffer to use easily with `face recognition API`.So, I'm returning my result to a `Stream` which my `face recognition API` will utilize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`using (bmp = new MemoryStream())` causes `bmp` object is destroyed on end using block. And You return `bmp` variable which is destroyed.

Remove using:

```
private Stream StreamFromBitmapSource(BitmapSource writeBmp)
{
    Stream bmp = new MemoryStream();

    BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(writeBmp));
    enc.Save(bmp);                                             

   return bmp;
}
```

Comment: `ReadTimeout = 'imgStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`    `WriteTimeout = 'imgStream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`  Thanks for helping me out. But now I'm facing trouble with these two exceptions

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are creating `bmp` inside an `using`, that's why it has been disposed before you return it (it is disposed once you leave the using) and that explains the exceptions you receive.

```
private Stream StreamFromBitmapSource(BitmapSource writeBmp)
{
    Stream bmp= new MemoryStream();
    using (enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder())
    {                    
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(writeBmp));
        enc.Save(bmp);                                     
    }

   return bmp;
}
```

Comment: `ReadTimeout = 'imgStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`    `WriteTimeout = 'imgStream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`  Thanks for helping me out. But now I'm facing trouble with these two exceptions

Comment: Could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172110/readtimeout-exception-with-memorystream

Comment: No, It isn't helping and I'm using `BitmapSource` instead of `Bitmap`