# Error converting byte array to image and trying to save

Tags: c#, image, base64

I receive the below error when trying to save an image which is converted from a byte array and not too sure why. Unfortunately, the error doesn't provide much detail on what the actual problem is. Error and code below

Error:

> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

and code:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
Image image;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
image = Image.FromStream(ms);
image.Save("testImage.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

EDIT: this error is thrown on the image.Save line

Comment: Which platform are you using. WPF?

Comment: I am pretty sure, yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find reason for Generic GDI+ error when saving an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571022/how-to-find-reason-for-generic-gdi-error-when-saving-an-image)

Comment: Try disposing of the `MemoryStream` object before saving the image in case it holds a lock on it

Comment: @Verdolino I tried converting to a bitmap before saving it, the same error occurs

Comment: @TheLethalCoder this does not solve the issue, same error occurs

Comment: @peggy there are many other solutions on that page. Make sure you have exhausted them all.

Comment: Do you/your application have write permission to the folder it's in? In the _Program Files_ folders you usually don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small test method like your code that looks like the below:

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

    //Your code
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes);
    image = Image.FromStream(ms2);
    image.Save("testImage.tif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
}
```

The only difference from my code to yours is that it uses a .tif image as input to get the `base64String`.

When I have tested this it works fine with no error, therefore I suggest you check a few things:

- The application has Read and Write permissions to the current directory
- The `testImage.png` is not locked by another process
- The `base64String` is valid and not providing errors
- The `image` when loaded looks fine, i.e. display it in a `PictureBox` if your application runs in `WindowsForms`