# How to save a bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, save

In WPF I have a Bitmap coming from a library which deals with my webcam

```
Bitmap bmp = webCameraControl.GetCurrentImage();
```

now I have to save it but bmp.Save("C:/img.jpg"); fails
So I tried

```
bmp.Save("C:/img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

but it didn't work and got

> "Generic GDI+ error".

Thanks

---ADD---

So if I put

```
bmp.Save("C:\\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bmp.Save(@"C:\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I get error.
But if I put

```
bmp.Save("img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

That works!! I can't understand!=?!?

Comment: Someone found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571022/how-to-find-reason-for-generic-gdi-error-when-saving-an-image Worth to try.

Comment: Of course, now you save into a local directory, relative to the project folder (or the exe). Your program most likely does not have write right to the root. Pick something like C:\temp\...

Answer (score 4):

"Generic GDI+ error". mostly will occur if the path does not exist to the directory where you want to store it.

- Check if the path exist
- Check if the path is vallid

`bmp.Save("C:\\Test\\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);`
make sure you use `\\` or `@"C:\Test\img.jpg"`

If this all is not working you maybe have no rights to save to `C:\\`

Comment: Yes, I dit write it whit two \\ but the textbox is making on think because sql injections

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried another location to save the image to?
I guess that this directory is protected by windows itself.

**Solution:**

Right click your project file on the Solution Explorer, select Add, then New item. There you can find Application Manifest File.

It creates file called *app.manifest*. Open it and find the tag *requestedPrivileges*. (like shown below)

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <!-- ##GERMAN TEXT##

    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" /> ##GERMAN TEXT##
    -->
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
```

The line you are interested in is this one:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

It sais you execute it as the invoker ("asInvoker").
Change it to "requireAdministrator" and restart VisualStudio as administrator.

This should make it :)

## EDIT

I forgot to mention that I tried it with these 2 lines of code.
It works for me, when I run it as administrator.

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(12,12);
        bmp.Save("C:/img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the issue you have is with the "/" in your save path.  You can write it one of two ways:

`bmp.Save("C:\\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); //two backslashes escapes to a single backslash`

`bmp.Save(@"C:\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); //adding @ escapes the backslash automatically`

**Edit** [I found this over at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/217504/is-there-a-list-of-windows-special-directories-shortcuts-like-temp), you might be able to get around using `C:\` using this.  Use the path `"%HomeDrive%\\img.jpg"`, which is a built in path shortcut to `C` drive.  I don't know how reliably this works from C#, but it worked last time I tried it and it works when I tested in the file explorer right now.

Write permissions to that directory seem the most likely problem for you though.  If that is the case, I don't know what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
public static void RotateAndSaveImage(string path, WriteableBitmap bitmap, double angle)
{
    try
    {
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            var tb = new TransformedBitmap((bitmap), new RotateTransform(angle));
            var src = tb as BitmapSource;

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));
                encoder.Save(stream);
            }
        }
    } catch {}
}
```

Comment: Oh, what is happening exactly? I will immediately <3

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like below:

```
private void RotateAndSaveImage(int pageNumber, double angleOfRotation)
  {
     EnsureNotDisposed();

     // create the encoder
     BitmapEncoder encoder = BitmapEncoder.Create(Decoder.CodecInfo.ContainerFormat);

     // copy the destination frames
     foreach (BitmapFrame frame in Decoder.Frames)
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

     BitmapFrame oldFrame = encoder.Frames[pageNumber - 1];

     // Create the TransformedBitmap to use as the Image source.
     TransformedBitmap tb = new TransformedBitmap();

     // Properties must be set between BeginInit and EndInit calls.
     tb.BeginInit();

     tb.Source = new CachedBitmap(oldFrame, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);

     RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform(angleOfRotation);
     tb.Transform = transform;

     tb.EndInit();

     encoder.Frames.RemoveAt(pageNumber - 1);
     encoder.Frames.Insert(pageNumber - 1, BitmapFrame.Create(tb));
     // save encoder
     Save(encoder)
  }
  
  /// <summary>
  /// Saves the contents of a bitmap encoder to <see cref="Stream"/>.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="encoder">
  /// The encoder from which to obtain the data to save.
  /// </param>
  private void Save(BitmapEncoder encoder)
  {
     // save to a temporary stream
     string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

     try
     {
        using (FileStream temporaryStream = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
           if (encoder.Frames.Count > 0)
              encoder.Save(temporaryStream);

           // write back out to permanent stream
           if (Stream.CanWrite && Stream.CanSeek)
              CopyStream(temporaryStream, Stream);
           else
              throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
     }
     finally
     {
        // Delete the temporary file
        File.Delete(tempFileName);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the bitmap into a stream and convert it into base64String. Once you have this its up to you what you want to do with it.

```
bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.png);
return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
```