# Saving Bitmap results in GDI+ Generic Error C#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, drawing, console-application

I'm trying to execute the following code in a Windows Console Application.

```
using (Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    using (Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
    {
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(bmpScreenshot);
        b.Save("image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
A Generic error happened in GDI+ at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   ved System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
```

Now, the weird thing is, If I run this program as "Run as Administrator" I don't get this error, and it works as intended.

The reason I don't want it to be "Run as Administrator" is that I need to it run on Computer Startup without using external VBScripts and other stuff like that.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: yopu probably don't have write access to the folder. You really ought to use a path to a suitable folder!

Comment: @TaW I tried switching the path to C:\image.jpg but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Well the root of the system disk is not a good choice either as it also has limited access. Try some other folder. Note that the generic gdi error is a catchall error for all sorts of errors, so this is just __one__ common cause.

Comment: @TaW I tried with the folder C:\RDP\image.jpg then it worked!

Comment: @TaW Thanks mate!

Comment: Duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571022/how-to-find-reason-for-generic-gdi-error-when-saving-an-image?rq=1)