# gdi+ error while save image in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gdi+, save-image

I have read and tried the solutions, but the problem is not solved. I get an gdi+ ​​error while saving a image.

```
            byte[] bytes1 = Convert.FromBase64String(t1);

            var randomFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) + ".png";
            var path1 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content", "images", "16x9", randomFileName);

            using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(bytes1))
            {
                System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms1);
                image1.Save(path1);
            }
```

Comment: what is the full error message you get?

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException occurred

A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595846/6671523

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Content\images\16x9\f652.png'. now it gives this error