# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

[image]

[image]

I try to resize an image but I want to do it in another class library.

When I send this, I get an error which I showed in the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is read/write permission.

```
using(var stream= new FileStream(filepath,FileModel.Create)){
    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
    // open the orginal image
    Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
    // error occurs here, we need to copy and paste it into a new object 
    // var img2 = new Bitmap(img);
    // img2.Save(i2newPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    Image newImage = ImageConverterHelper,JPEGConverter(img,filePath) 
    ...
}
```

For more details, you can check [the related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595846/7687666).

> by copying the image internally into a Bitmap instance and saving this image instead of the original image, the error disappeared.